# Setting ViewControllers on top of each other with opacity.

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I am a new Swift writer who is looking for an answer to a relatively specific question. Please forgive any novice mistakes.

I am trying to create a Pop Up on the screen programmatically that layers two view controllers so that one view controller is visible on the other, with a level of opacity that makes the background visible.

After a transition from my GameViewController see here:

```
let gameOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "gameOverID") as! GameOverViewController
    self.addChildViewController(gameOverVC)
    gameOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(gameOverVC.view)
    gameOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self) 
}
```

... I instantiate a ViewController of GameOverViewController to fit over the GameViewController. After that I go to my GameOverViewController class and attempt to set the background color to be opaque with the following line of code:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)
```

The problem is that I end up with is a background that is not opaque, when in reality I would rather the GameViewController to layer on top of the GameViewController with an opaque background to still be able to see the Game.

I also animate with the following within my GameOverViewController:

```
 func showAnimate()
{
    self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    self.view.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1.0
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    })
}

func removeAnimate()
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.view.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        if (finished)
            {
            self.view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    })
}
```

I'm not sure what is the source of my problem is.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you do the animation , then show the second VC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  background color of game over view Controller in interface builder like this

[image]

Also , take note of that you remove the game viewController's view in this line in removeAnimate func

```
   self.view.removeFromSuperview()
```

this may cause black background if you do it before showing game over VC

Answer (score 0):

for the view that sits on top, use: [overFullScreen](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle/1621506-overfullscreen)  and then simply present it.

```
let topVC = topVC()
topVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
self.present(VCTobePresented, animated: true, completion: nil)
```